# EE 3.x - Import from EE 2.x to EE 3.x all Snippets

Tags: snippets

I started with a fresh **EE 3.3.0** installation on my localhost.  However, I would like to bring over ALL the Snippets that I am using on my Production website to my brand new localhost EE 3.3.0 site.  I exported all the Snippets from the one site, imported them into the EE 3.3.0 site but I do not see them anyplace within EE.

I thought I had seen a note that Snippets had been replaced, but Snippets are referenced in the 3.3.0 Manual and it doesn't appear to have been deprecated.

1. Are Snippets still being used ?

   - Where do I find them in EE 3.3.0 ?
2. If they are no longer being used, what has replaced them ?

   - How do I bring over the existing Snippets into this new object (Table Name) ?

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is now called "Template Partials", uses the Snippets table (xxx_snippets  -- where xxx is replaced by your site's prefix".  You can export from the old xxx_snippets table and then insert this into your new xxx_snippets table.

However, if you have already created Template Partials then you have a couple of choices:
    a) Delete all existing Template Partials, perform the mas insert of the snippets and add all new Template Partials
    b) Edit the snippets SQL such that all the IDs are incremented OR set to NULL.
       - I personally believe the NULL idea would be best.